# woocommerce category visible in certain days

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to make certain woo categories to be visible as an example at ***Saturday*** & ***Sunday***?
On ***Monday*** should not be visible.
Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently displaying your categories, are they in the sidebar? Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP >= 5.1, you can use date('N') to check what day of the week it is today, with Monday = 1 to Sunday = 7

So you can do

```
if (date('N', $timestamp) === '1')) {
    echo "Today is Monday";
}
```

Alternatively you can check if today is the first day of the month by using

```
    if (date('j', $timestamp) === '1')) {
        echo "Today is the first day of the month";
    }
```

With this check then you can set you logic to not showing the category if it's not Monday